# Localstorage not storing URL

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm attempting to create a pop up modal with location options that redirect depending on user selection. I'm attempting to store the selected URL inside localstorage as a preference so that the user only has to choose their location once and not have to deal with pop ups every time they visit the site.

Every time I test this in browser the redirect is happening but when I enter a console.log to print out the localStorage value it's returning `null` I'm not getting any errors in the console so I don't have much to go off of.

My code is below and I've included a link to JS Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jkvstoyL/#&togetherjs=720CG6xl5w), any help is hugely appreciated!

```
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form name="siteSelector">
            <select onchange="save(); go()" id="site" name="site" SIZE="1" class="form-control form-control-lg">
                    <option value="non-value">Choose Site</option>
                    <option value="https://www.google.com">Google</option>
                    <option value="https://www.amazon.com/">Amazon</option>
                    <option value="https://www.guitarcenter.com/">Guitar Center</option>
            </select>
            <script>



                function save(){


                    document.getElementsByName("site").onchange = function(){
                        localStorage.setItem('site', document.getElementsByName("site"));
                    }



                    if (localStorage.getItem('site')) {
                        document.getElementsByName("site").options[localStorage.getItem('site')].selected = true;
                    }
                }

                function go(){
                    location = document.siteSelector.site.options[document.siteSelector.site.selectedIndex].value
                }


            </script>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('site', document.getElementsByName("site"));` is storing the entire `<select>` element, not the value of the selected option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to store a document element as localStorage item. You can store an index of selected option or URL.

In your sample `document.getElementsByName` returns NodeList - not a single element. Your save function can look like this:

```
function save () {
   let element = document.getElementById("site");
   if (!element.selectedIndex)
       return; // you can display error if that happens. 
   localStorage.setItem('site', element.selectedIndex);
}
```

Comment: I swapped that in and replaced my save function, but I'm still not able to pull the item from localstorage when I call it from the console. It's still coming back null or undefined.

Comment: Can you give me an updated code? I didn't saw changes at JsFiddle.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong! So after you select one of the links and hit the URL you're able to pull up the stored value from the console? I'm getting this error: `VM138:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs`

Comment: Yup, sure. I updated my example, you can see selected index in the console. When event started you can see an already stored index and then you can see an updated index.